# $n$th derivative of a function that depends both explicitly and implicitly on a variable

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

I would like to have a closed-formula for the $n$th derivative of a function of the type $f(x,g(x))$, i.e. a function that depends both explicitly and implicitly on a (scalar) variable:
$$
\frac{d^n f}{d x^n} = ?
$$
It can be assumed that all partial derivatives up to order $n$ included exist.

I can calculate the first (or second, or third...) derivatives by hand by using the chain rule. For example:
$$
\frac{d f}{d x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = f^{(1,0)} + g'f^{(0,1)}.
$$
or
$$
\frac{d^2 f}{d x^2} =  f^{(2, 0)} +  2 g' f^{(1, 1)} + (g')^2 f^{(0, 2)} + g'' f^{(0, 1)}
$$

I however cannot see a pattern for a general formula. I am aware of the Faà di Bruno formula for calculating high order derivatives of a purely implicit function, but I am failing in seeing how to use it in combination with an explicit dependence of the function on the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general higher derivative of a composition can be calculated by [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) (Higher Chain rule). Faà di Bruno's formula can be represented i.a. by [Exponential Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

[[Hardy 2006]](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1r1) generalizes Faà di Bruno's formula to the general higher partial derivatives of a multivariate function.

The answer to your question is given in [[Bernardini/Natalini/Ricci 2005]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122105004190?via%3Dihub):
"**Abstract** - We develop some extensions of the classical Bell polynomials, previously obtained, by introducing a further class of these polynomials called multidimensional Bell polynomials of higher order. They arise considering the derivatives of functions $f$ in several variables $\varphi^{(i)}$, $(i=1,2,...,m)$, where $\varphi^{(i)}$ are composite functions of different orders, i.e. $\varphi^{(i)}(t)=\phi^{(i,1)}(\phi^{(i,2)}(...(\phi^{(i,r_i)}(t)))$, $(i=1,2,...,m)$. We show that these new polynomials are always expressible in terms of the ordinary Bell polynomials, by means of suitable recurrence relations or formal multinomial expansions. Moreover,
we give a recurrence relation for their computation."

Comment: Equation 3.2 in that article seems to be what I was looking for, in the special case in which $m=2$ and $\phi_1 = t$. I do not need to involve multidimensional Bell polynomial of higher order, but only the multidimensional Bell polynomial, which are back referenced to [Noschese et al., JCAA 2003](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1023227705558). Thanks!